# Why Algebra has continuing research while for something like Calculus, there is none.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, abstract-algebra, analysis, research

Why does the nature of algebra provide such a vast amount of research to be conducted with so many new discoveries while something like calculus is essentially complete.  Is there a good reason as to what this "property" is?  I imagine this questions is akin to "Is there an end to scientific discovery," but will algebraic discoveries ever be complete in the same sense that calculus is?  I have somewhat of an idea but I would like to hear what other people have to say.

Comment: There is still research in the area calculus is in; but it’s not called “calculus”: it’s called “analysis”. Calculus is to analysis like “college algebra” is to abstract algebra.

Comment: generally the research is a mix of algebra and analysis, so they are developed at once. Im not sure if algebra or analysis tend to be more present.

Comment: Personal opinion: calculus is so dry. The theorems are boring and the computation is tedious. Now, analysis - that's the fun way to do calculus. Analysis is great, but calc - eh, it's kinda dry.